# Is there a minimum energy content of information, other than 0 Joules?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, information

Lets say I want to send the bit string 010110 to someone. Is there a theoretical lower bound on the energy needed to do this?

Comment: OK, so I edited this to remove the superluminal stuff -- obviously rankled someone out there...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_in_thermodynamics_and_information_theory#Szilard.27s_engine

Answer (score 5):

See e.g. [Landauer's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle)  and [capacity of noisy channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity).

Not everybody agrees with these limits, but to me they seem fairly reasonable based on relatively straight forward noise arguments. In an ideal world (i.e. temperature T=0), there is no lower limit for the energy needed to store a bit, in the real world, however, noise will interfere and the third law of thermodynamics guarantees T>0, i.e. that there is always noise. As a consequence, one has to have enough energy (and in case of information transmission, enough power) to be above the noise floor, to make a distinction between ones and zeros.

None of this, however, has anything to do with superluminal information transmission. The people who use dispersive systems to attempt to produce superluminal phase velocities for information transmission have not been able to demonstrate, that they are actually superluminal (albeit, in my opinion, some may have demonstrated, that they don't know how information is defined in physics).

Comment: Landauer's principle doesn't apply to storing or transmitting bits. In fact it says that in principle neither of these things take any energy. Landauer's principle says the only thing that takes energy is erasing bits, which isn't needed for transmitting them. (The points about the noise floor are quite reasonable though.)

Comment: Your response and the one below point to an issue I didn't consider, which is the nature of the limit at 0 Joules. While the limit may be 0, any actual signal will require >0 Joules, hence information always has a strictly positive energy content...correct?

Comment: @Nathaniel: In order to read a bit, you have to take some energy out of the storage mechanism. If that amount of energy equals the total energy of the storage medium, then the readout will erase the bit, hence Landauer's limit is also the limit for the read process. If you want to keep the information for consecutive reads, you will need more energy than the Landauer limit.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: Yes, pretty much. What it means is, that  one can drive the limit down as far as one wants, provided, that one keeps the storage media and reading mechanisms at a low enough temperature.

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a minimum energy content of information?*

Carl Witthoft's answer gives us a key hint: in terms of energy efficiency one can't really do better than using photons to encode bits.

A photon residing in a container of linear size $R$ has minimum energy $\Delta E \approx \hbar c / R$. By increasing the size $R$ one can reduce the energy per bit below any desired value. Still, the number of bits $N$ one can store using total energy $E$ is limited by the product $E$ times $R$: $$N < \frac{E}{\Delta E} \approx \frac{E R}{\hbar c}$$
This, in essence, is the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound), an upper limit to the information that can be contained within a given finite region of space which has a finite amount of energy.

Comment: Provided that your container is so cold, that the quantum mechanical limit, rather than the thermodynamic limit applies, which, I believe, is practically never.

Comment: Sure, but OP explicitly asks for a *theoretical* (rather than a practical) lower bound.

Comment: The theoretical lower bound is zero, even in the quantum mechanical case. Interestingly, cosmology seems to indicate, that that's exactly, where the universe is going...

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to look at the problem,  but:

Suppose you send one photon for a "1" and no photon for a "0" according to some prearranged clock.  What's the lowest possible photon energy?  The answer, of course, is "asymptotically approaching zero."

Not that I'd like to build an antenna capable of detecting a photon with $\lambda > 1$ parsec.

Comment: The problem is, that your antenna is also suffering from thermal noise, i.e. it picks up photons from the background radiation of the universe. If you want to cool it down below the background, you have to expend energy, which drives the energy cost of detecting these photons higher than this limit suggests.

Comment: @CuriousOne  Agreed;  my point was that in a "assume a universe devoid of all photons except the signal ones (and a spherical ... :-)  ) " there's no strict limit.

Comment: I think the zero limit is correct, even with background radiation... it just happens that the temperature in a universe filled with lots of radiation and matter drops much slower, than it would in one with less (or none... but that wouldn't even be a universe, would it?). Either way, nature seems to be headed towards very large, very cold and... very boring.